# SuiteScript - Can't Upload File

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm a complete newbie to SuiteScript and NetSuite. I've been following the HelloWorld tutorial [here](https://1291624-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_1503717063.html) and have gotten to the point where I upload the script file to NetSuite. I follow the directions and upload it to the SuiteScripts directory - and every time it fails with the error "SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function."

Here's the entire script file - what is wrong with it? I can't see anything.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/ui/dialog'],
function(dialog){
function helloWorld()    {
    var options = {
        title : 'Hello!',
        message : 'Hello, World!'
    };
    try {
        dialog.alert(options);
        log.debug(
        {
            title : 'Success',
            details : 'Alert displayed successfully'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        log.error({
            title : e.name,
            details : e.message
        });
    }
};

return{
    pageInit : helloWorld
};
});
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the file. (There's an unnecessary semi-colon after the helloWorld function but that won't cause a problem.) Are you sure you're attempting to upload the correct file?

Comment: I believe so - it's the only *.js file there is. The only other file in the directory is the eclipse .project file.

I assume the source directory on my PC doesn't matter.

Is there anywhere in particular in the FileCabinet I should be uploading it to? It wouldn't let me upload to the root at all; I just created a directory named 'BF Test' to upload it to.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get this error.
I usually fix this by checking the character encoding, making sure it has '.js' file extension added in the filename and make sure that it does not have any extra spaces in front of the '.js' file extension

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this code once?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
require(['N/ui/dialog'],
function(dialog){
function helloWorld(context)    {
    var options = {
        title : 'Hello!',
        message : 'Hello, World!'
    };
    try {
        dialog.alert(options);
        log.debug(
        {
            title : 'Success',
            details : 'Alert displayed successfully'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        log.error({
            title : e.name,
            details : e.message
        });
    }
};

return{
    pageInit : helloWorld
}
});
```